# Python pandas: dynamically naming loaded CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop, file-rename

I'm reading in a selection of consistently named CSV files from the same directory. I'm looking to load them such that the variable names change based on the file name, i.e.:

```py
food_list=['apples','oranges','pears']
place_list=['bodega','grocery']

for i in range(0, len(food_list)):
    for j in range(0,len(place_list)):
        grocery=pd.read_csv(str(food_list[i])+'_'+str(place_list[j])+'_train.csv')
        new_name=str(food_list[i])+'_'+str(place_list[j])+'_train'
        train=new_name
        test=pd.read_csv(str(food_list[i])+'_'+str(place_list[j])+'_test.csv')
        new_name=str(food_list[i])+'_'+str(place_list[j])+'_test'
        test=new_name

### Desired output:
apples_bodega_train # is a dataframe
apples_bodega_test # is a dataframe
...
pears_grocery_train # is a dataframe
pears_grocery_test # is a dataframe

### Actual output:
train # pears_grocery_train
test # pears_grocery_test
```

So, I'm clearly just overwriting the loaded CSV dataframe names "train" and "test" within each loop iteration with other useless variable names, versus just **renaming the loaded dataframes**. Could someone enlighten me regarding the intelligent way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would actually be possible with the eval() function, but that's definitely not what you want to do. How about saving the dataframes in a dictionary? Like This:

```
dataframes = dict()
dataframes[str(food_list[i])+'_'+str(place_list[j])+'_train'] = pd.read_csv(str(food_list[i])+'_'+str(place_list[j])+'_train.csv')
dataframes[str(food_list[i])+'_'+str(place_list[j])+'_test'] = pd.read_csv(str(food_list[i])+'_'+str(place_list[j])+'_test.csv')
```

Comment: Great- this allows me to access each dataframe with the following syntax: dataframes['apple_bodega_train'] and so on. Thank you!